# CSS selector of first child, if multiple exist

Tags: css, computer-science

I have this as part of one of my tables.

```
<header>
  <h1>...</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <h2>...</h2>
  <dl>
    <dt>...</dt>
    <dd>...</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>...</dt>
    <dd>...</dd>
  </dl>
</header>
```

How do can I select just the first dt? The one that containts Calories in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dl:first-child dt {
    // ...
}
```

Since the `dl` is *not the first child* as described in comments, you'll need a different selector:

```
dl:first-of-type dt {
    // ...
}
```

Or — just give the `dt` a class.

Comment: Its within a header. Does that change anything?

Comment: Yes. There are h1 and h2 before it. But they are on the same level as the dl, inside the header.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
dl > dt:first-child{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Using it every first `<dt>` element `background-color` under `<dl>` element is turned red.